# Event emitter - UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm firing an event to send an email from my controller but when nodemailer fails to send the email for good reasons like password and username being wrong, i get a unhandled promise rejection error in stack trace. I also emit an error when node mailer fails to send the email,listen to it and then throw another error but it isn't reaching the controller level to be handled by the try catch.

this is the method in the controller where i fire the event

```
 sendMail = async(emitterPayload: any): Promise<any> => {
    try {= 
       
      //other asynchronous operations
      EventEmitter.emit('SEND MAIL', emitterPayload);      

    } catch (err) {
      throw new Error(err);
    }
  };
```

How i listen to 'SEND MAIL' event. When no error , the email is sent successfully

```
EventEmitter.on(
  'SEND MAIL',
   (emitterPayload) =>  {
 
     NodeMailerService.sendEmail(emitterPayload).catch(function(error) {
    //fire this event when error occurs
    EventEmitters.emit('error',new Error(error));
  });

  },
);
```

When an 'error' is fired, i listen to it like this

```
EventEmitter.on(
  'error',
  err => {
      throw new Error(err);
  },
);
```

But i instead get `Unhandled promise rejection`. How can i throw an error as shown above and have my controller handle it. What i'm i missing or doing wrong?

the complete error

```
 UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:12960) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code
```

Comment: Maybe you did not handle your final error where you actually do throwing it: `EventEmitter.on('error'... throw new Error...` ?

Comment: @tarkh i expected the controller to handle that but it looks like it ends at the EventEmitter level